# Button on Graph point in Core-plot? Objective-C

Tags: xcode, button, graph, core-plot, drag

I'm currently working on a project where I present several circles in a graph, where some circles are dependant others. I have 1 circle which has its origin in (0.0, 0.0), and another circle (let's call them circle1 and circle2) which has its origin on an angle position on circle1. So I calculate the origin position of circle2 by deciding an angle and calculate that angle towards circle1's local graph. By doing this I get an x and y position for a specific angle in the local graph for circle1. On the point (x, y) I then draw circle2.

However, I would like the user to be able to interact with circle2. More precisely I want to be able to change the angle from which circle2 was drawn by adding some sort of slider, which on the user drags in order to change the angle and then redraws the circle2.

Clarification: What I want to do is to add a button to the HostedView and drag it around in the view. Is this possible in Core plot?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add buttons or other views to the Core Plot hosting view. Add it to the hosting view's parent view and position it on top of the hosting view.

Comment: Hmm, I did add it to the hostingView and it worked fine. But I changed from a button to a imageView instead which I can move around. I added it to the hostingView and are now constrained to move it around in that view alone, which turns out is exactly what I wanted.